Do I need to use REGEX/URL rewriting for my BeEF / Nginx reverse proxy config?
I am running BeEF on an Nginx Virtual Server, behind Nginx which is acting as a reverse proxy. Furthermore, the webpage which the BeEF hook will sit on is also on a separate virtual server, also sitting behind Nginx Reverse Proxy.
The goal is for all client requests and responses to be HTTPS, which are changed by Nginx from 443 to the port that the respective server is expecting.
The main scenario I would like to request some guidance on is that of the BeEF server and it's Nginx config.
BeEF is confiured to listen on port 3000, and is assigned an virtual IP internal to the Debian server.
Ideally, I would like to have a REFEX that enables something like this diagram, but I am not confident enough in REGEX to do so.
|Client| --> Sends HTTPS request --> | Nginx| ----> Rewritten URL HTTP ------> | BeEF|
   eg  https://my.domain/f.js    Takes everything   eg http://1.1.1.1/f.js
       https://my.domain/f1/f2   after my.domain       http://1.1.1.1/f1/f2
                                 and appends to 
                                 server IP

So I have attempted to hard code the two main URL re-writes as you will see below - but it is not working !! Currently when I test form client side browser Im getting 404 error.
Here is the relevant server block (located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/beefapp.conf)
server {

#       listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mt.domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mt.domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name my.domain
        set $upstream 172.31.5.154:3000;

        location /f1/f2 {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://$upstream/f1/f2;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_redirect off;

        }

        location /f {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://$upstream/f.js;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_redirect off;

        }

If relevant here is an excerpt of my BeEF config.yaml:
# HTTP server                                                                                http:                                                                                            debug: false #Thin::Logging.debug, very verbose. Prints also full exception stack tr>        host: "172.31.5.154"
    port: "3000"

    # Decrease this setting to 1,000 (ms) if you want more responsiveness
    #  when sending modules and retrieving results.
    # NOTE: A poll timeout of less than 5,000 (ms) might impact performance
    #  when hooking lots of browsers (50+).
    # Enabling WebSockets is generally better (beef.websocket.enable)
    xhr_poll_timeout: 1000

    # Public Domain Name / Reverse Proxy / Port Forwarding
    #
    # In order for the client-side BeEF JavaScript hook to be able to connect to BeEF,
    # the hook JavaScript needs to be generated with the correct connect-back details.
    #
    # If you're using a public domain name, reverse proxy, or port forwarding you must
    # configure the public-facing connection details here.

    #public:
        host: "my.domain" # public hostname/IP address
        port: "443" # public port (443 if the public server is using HTTPS)
        https: true # true/false

    # If using any reverse proxy you should also set allow_reverse_proxy to true below.
    # Note that this causes the BeEF server to trust the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header.
    # If the BeEF server is directly accessible, clients can spoof their connecting
    # IP address using this header to bypass the IP address permissions/exclusions.
    allow_reverse_proxy: true


Upon further investigation, I am of the understanding that perhaps I can use something like:
set $upstream 172.31.5.154:3000
location my.domain/ {
proxy_pass http://$upstream$request_uri}

Would this work? Essentially using $REQUEST_URI to achieve the goal I was illustrating in the diagram?
